# I want the Siri to open when I click button. Is it possible?

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit

I added a button to my application. I want the Siri to open when I click this button. Is it possible? How can I do that? Please, help.

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, you can do a lot of things with Siri but not call it directly. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit) is the apple documentation for SiriKit that show you what you can do with it.